# How to make a connection between linux machine to microsoft sql server

Tags: linux

I wanted to make a connection to my microsoft sql server 2008 from RHEL 5 32 bit.I was not able to find odbc drivers for the same.

Comment: have you checked this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx

Comment: In Ubuntu you need to install unixodbc and tdsodbc (FreeTDS). You'll need the equivalent RHEL packages. Then add your connection information to odbc.ini, odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the link however this link has only RHEL 64 bit drivers.I dont see 32 bit...